# Why is const ignored at "the outermost level of the parameter type"?

Tags: c++

I read a textbook and met this paragraph:

> Nontype template parameters are declared much like variables, but they cannot have nontype specifiers like static, mutable, and so forth. They can have const and volatile qualifiers, but if such
> a qualifier appears at the outermost level of the parameter type, it is simply ignored:

```
template<int const length> class Buffer; // const is useless here
template<int length> class Buffer; // same as previous declaration
```

I don't really understand what it means **if such
a qualifier appears at the outermost level of the parameter type, it is simply ignored**.
That is, in templates where we specify parameters, it does not make sense to set const? but I thought I'd seen it done many times before.or does it imply something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value template arguments can only be compile-time constants. It's not possible to use variables or other run-time data. So `const` isn't needed, it's understood that the value *must* already be a constant.